# VisualStudio: turn off types hints (Resharper but not CodeLens)

Tags: c#, resharper, code-editor

How to turn off types hints in the C# code editor of Visual Studio 2019?

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to be using resharper?

Comment: That was also my thought. Maybe this is really about [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (R#); in that case, the tags should be edited accordingly.

Comment: "ReSharper | Options | Environment | Editor | Inlay Hints" - from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html

Comment: For the R# hints, right-click on a hint anywhere in the code and select Hide all hints from the context menu

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to the comments on the question I managed to find out  this is the R# option is called 'inlay hints' and it can be configured and turned off in resharper option menu.

```
VS -> Tools -> Options -> Resharper Ultimate -> Options -> Environment -> Editor -> Inlay Hints
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're using ReSharper. And this hints are called [Inlay Hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inline_Parameter_Name_Hints.html)